# How to determine when a user has liked a facebook app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I'm working on a facebook app, hosted on canvas, where until the user likes the app, he is shown a message saying 'Like us for bla bla bla', and only when he's liked it is he given access to the app.

How can I check that he's liked the app via the API? Which graph object / method do I need to use, or do I need to use FQL?